# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, soap

I have two web service functions which have the exact same interface (calling from C#/Winform application):

`string[] f1(int, string[])` and `string[] f2(int, string[])`

to which I'm sending the exact same data. When I call f1, it works just fine and returns a string[], however, when I call f2, I get a SOAPException saying that the "input string is not a correct format".

What could be causing one to work and the other not to work?

```
    private void backgroundWorkerUploadNew_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> submittedList = new List<String>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.textBoxFilename.Text);
        String data;

        while ((data = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            submittedList.Add(data);
        }
        reader.Close();
        // Send array of handset names to service
        int channelId = 0;
        string[] listToSubmit = submittedList.ToArray();
        channelId = AppStatus.CurrentChannel.ChannelID;
        String[] newHandsetsList = service.Function2(channelId, listToSubmit);
        ...
    }
```

The web service method

```
public List<String> Function2(int integer, List<String> strings)
{
    List<String> newList = new List<string>();
    DataTable tempDt = null;
    foreach (String s in strings)
    {
        String q = @"** SOME QUERY **";
        tempDt = Database.RunSql(q);
        ...
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: does the string contain a date?

Comment: Dennis, can you post the code snippet?

Comment: Also add the data you are sending. Are both services running on the same machine?

Comment: Dennis, the method signatures alone won't be enough to help you. You need to list some of the method internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message comes from the Parse method (for numeric types, DateTime, etc.). If the computers are using different cultures, the correct format would be different. If that is the problem, you might be able to solve it by using the invariant culture.

Comment: Solved: Well, it wasn't a culture problem, but rather trying to change a DataRow into an int, when I was trying to get the value in the cell (an sql Count() number).